# SwiftUI: How to get path to JSON in app group?

Tags: ios, json, swiftui, safari-extension, ios-app-group

I have an app group that contains a very simple JSON file I have created. Im using the content blocker extension and instead of accessing the content of "blockerlist" i would like to access the content of the JSON in the App group.
But how can I do this?

I have done this once before so I know it should be fairly simple, but for some reason I just can not figure it out again.

Any ideas?

I have created a comment above all the data that is necessary to do this.

```
class ContentBlockerRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {
    // here
    let contentBlockerId = "myid"

    func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {
         // here
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: contentBlockerId)
         // here
        let archiveURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("myList.json")

        // here
        let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blockerlist", withExtension: "json"))!
        
        let item = NSExtensionItem()
        item.attachments = [attachment]
        
        context.completeRequest(returningItems: [item], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
}
```